# Objective C - UITableView visual changes appearing in false if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, if-statement

I have a Calendar list in a UITableView and I'm changing the color of the cell to indicate if the event is today. This is working, all the cells which events are today are changing color but as I scroll up and down other cells are changing color (cells that are not for today.) I `NSLogged` whenever the if statement was fired and it was only getting called on the correct cells (cells for todays events.)

The following code is inside my `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *event = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[event setYear:year];
[event setMonth:month];
[event setDay:day];

CFGregorianDate currentDate = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(), CFTimeZoneCopySystem());

if ((currentDate.year == event.year) && (currentDate.month == event.month) && (currentDate.day == event.day))
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(209/255.0) green:(247/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1];
    NSLog(@"Current Date    : %d/%d/%d", currentDate.day, currentDate.month, currentDate.year);
    NSLog(@"Item Date       : %ld/%ld/%ld", (long)event.day, (long)event.month, (long)event.year);
    NSLog(@"-");
}
```

I would be thankful if anyone could share their thoughts on why the cells which are not for today are changing color. Is this a visual bug in iOS because the `NSLogging` of the inside the if statement is only logging for the correct cells? Tested in iOS 7 & iOS 8 Beta 5.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to check your `if` statement's condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you are creating your cell with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` or related.

Because you are reusing cells, you're effectively getting one that you have already displayed before, perhaps one that had the background color changed.

A best practice when configuring a cell for `UITableView` is to never leave if statements without else statements handling the other case.

In your situation, you should add:

```
else {
    cell.backgroundColor = //whatver color is the non-selected
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I did not realize `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` would reuse cells already inside the the UITableView.

Comment: Yep, it's a pretty cool system. At peak a tableView creates as many cells as it needs to fill the screen, plus one probably.